# Salt is not stored in the database in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

In yii2,the table structure for the user table does not include a `salt` column.

```
 $this->createTable('tbl_user', [
        'id' => Schema::TYPE_PK,
        'username' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL',
        'auth_key' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . '(32) NOT NULL',
        'password_hash' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL',
        'password_reset_token' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . '(32)',
        'email' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL',
        'role' => Schema::TYPE_SMALLINT . ' NOT NULL DEFAULT 10',

        'status' => Schema::TYPE_SMALLINT . ' NOT NULL DEFAULT 10',
        'create_time' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER.' NOT NULL',
        'update_time' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER.' NOT NULL',
    ], $tableOptions);
```

This really make me confused. Although Yii uses a salted hash, its not stored in the database by default. Should i rewrite the code to make it store in  the database?What if i do not sore the salt in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This salt, used in [Yii2 Security helper](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseSecurity.php) doesn't require for storing in db, it is only used for creating password hash, but not need to compare password with hash. So it's pretty secure.

Comment: So..why people store salt in db next to the password hash?

Comment: Also when I post back the data from loginForm,i am getting it in clear text. Its not secure rit?

Comment: storing salt is an old school method. You can check php functions http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Thanks! What about my post data(username,password)?I am getting it as clear text while checking it with proxy!

Comment: sorry can't say anything about this issue, may be you'll ask it in another question?

Comment: Added a new question!Please see my new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268252/yii2-username-and-password-encryption